# Sequences formed by integer evaluations of polynomials modulo $ p^{k} $, where $ p $ is a prime number and $ k \in \Bbb{N} $.

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I have the following question.

> Let $ p $ be a prime number and $ k $ a positive integer. Let $ (a_{n})_{n \in \Bbb{Z}} $ be a two-way sequence in $ \Bbb{Z} / p^{k} \Bbb{Z} $. Then is it true that $ (a_{n})_{n \in \Bbb{Z}} $ is periodic with period $ p^{l} $ for some $ l \in \Bbb{N}_{0} $ if and only if there exists a numerical polynomial $ f $ such that $ (a_{n})_{n \in \Bbb{Z}} = \left( f(n) + p^{k} \Bbb{Z} \right)_{n \in \Bbb{Z}} $?

**Note:** We say that $ f $ is a numerical polynomial if and only if $ f \in \Bbb{Q}[X] $ and $ f(n) \in \Bbb{Z} $ for all $ n \in \Bbb{Z} $. For example, $ \dfrac{1}{2} X^{2} + \dfrac{1}{2} X = \dfrac{1}{2} X (X + 1) $ is a numerical polynomial, so a numerical polynomial is not necessarily an element of $ \Bbb{Z}[X] $.

Using the method of finite differences, one can prove that the answer is ‘yes’ for any prime number $ p $ and $ k = 1 $, but that is as far as I have gone.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One direction is easy:
Let the sequence be given by a numeric polynomial $f$. Then $mp^rf\in\mathbb Z[X]$ for some $r\ge 0$ and $m$ coprime to $p$. Hence $mp^rf(X+p^l)\equiv mp^r f(X)\pmod {p^l}$. With $l\ge k+r$ this gives us $f(x+p^l)\equiv f(x)\pmod{p^k}$ for all $x\in\mathbb Z$, i.e., the sequence is periodic.

For the other direction we can use the method of finite differences. All we need is that after finitely many steps, the difference sequence becomes constant zero. For this note that the influence of an original entry in the $n$th differrence row is given by someting like $(-1)^i{n\choose i}$. In row $n=p^l$, the outer binomial coefficients $\pm1$ cancel by periodicity and all others are multiples of $p^l$. Hence difference row $p^l$ is divisble by $p^l$ (and again periodic). Repeating the proces, we sooner or later end up with a row divisible by $p^k$, as desired